# Transponer columnas en SQL con PIVOT ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguien me puede explicar fácilmente un ejemplo con PIVOT para transponer columnas por filas en sql.

Tengo varios datos representados así:

```
FECHA                ERROR1    ERROR2 
2017-01-01           12        23
```

Y me gustaría transponerlos así:

```
FECHA             TIPO DE ERROR      TOTAL
2017-01-01        ERROR1             12
2017-01-01        ERROR2             23
```

El código que tengo:

```
SELECT [1] as Fecha, [2] as TìpoError, [3] as Total
FROM
(SELECT ERROR1,ERROR2
    FROM Errores) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(ERROR1)
FOR ERROR1, ERROR2 IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS TablaEjemplo;
```

No encuentro un ejemplo que sea sencillo para avanzar con esta consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo he resuelto con UNPIVOT tal que así.

```
select u.Fecha, u.TipoError, u.Total
from errores s
unpivot
(
  total
  for TipoError in (ERROR1, ERROR2)
) u;
```